# operator= bout side one by value second by refrence?

Tags: c++

the Q is how to this kind of operator=
that it will work on:

int t = v[3]; // her i return by Value

v[3] = 8 ; // her i need to return by refrence (pointer to V[3] add')

will V is a Vector class (template class in my case)

```
 template <class T> 
 T& Vector<T>::operator[](const int Index) const
 {
  if(Index > -1 && Index < this->Size)
  {
    return &this->Array[Index];
  }
else
   {
        cerr <<"VECTOR_INVALID_INDEX"<<endl;
        return NULL;
   }
};
```

Comment: And.. What, exactly, is the problem with the code you posted? Is it compilation error on `return NULL;`? Note: references can't be equal to `NULL`.

Comment: The typical way of handling this is to use a const and a non-const overload of operator[]:  `const T& Vector<T>::operator[](const int Index) const;` `T& Vector<T>::operator[](const int Index);`.  You don't need to return by value; a new variable like `int t` will be able to bind to both the reference and const reference return values.

Comment: References are not pointers, and vice versa. There's no such thing as a null reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in this example. `this` is already a pointer. Doing `&this` is almost certainly not what you meant to do here. The other problem you are having is that you are returning a reference to `T` but `this` is const in this context. `this->Array[Index]` is `const T` which cannot bind to `T&`. Add a const and return `const T&` instead. Thirdly, `this->Size` is not calling the method Size, you forgot parentheses. The fourth problem is a reference binding to NULL. You will have to decide on another approach. The usual way to indicate that an operation cannot be completed is to throw an exception. [std::vector::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) throws [std::out_of_range](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) from header stdexcept.

```
template <class T>
const T& Vector<T>::operator[](const int Index) const
//^^^ add const here
{
    if (Index > -1 && Index < this->Size())
    //                  Add parentheses ^^ 
    {
        return this->Array[Index];
        //     ^ No need for &
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("VECTOR_INVALID_INDEX");
    }
};
```

You will probably want to add a non-const version as well, since this will fail for the example `v[3] = 8;`. Define this method as well with the same body :

```
T& Vector<T>::operator[](const int Index);
```

Comment: Your _fixed_ operator overload, still has compilation errors: `return NULL;` from a method which returns a reference.

Comment: return null is want the number is -1 or bigger then the stack it know to the assinmant thanks!!!!

Comment: how to work this: T     operator=(const T* Element);

that the  two operator work bout?